# what is "foo" used for in "def function(foo):" when using Python3.x

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I'm just wondering about something in Python3.x.

What is the `foo` in `def function(foo):` used for when you can use `def function():` too?

I know there is a difference, I just don't understand the definitions I have found in various books and tutorials.

Comment: `foo` is a function parameter. It has nothing specifically to do with Python 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easier to show than to explain, here's an example:

```
def function():
    print("Hello")
```

This function will *ALWAYS* print `Hello`, regardless on the user. Now take a look at this function:

```
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```

As you can see, we're printing `foo` (called function parameter) instead of a string. This way, when we call the function, we can (and in this case, we **must**) replace the `foo` in the function call with any value, and that value will be set to `foo`. It's basically a local variable inside the function, which will be defined by the user when the function is called.

Few examples:

```
 In[1]: function("Hey")
Out[1]: "Hey"
 In[2]: function(5)
Out[2]: 5
```

Comment: If the answer pleases you, remember to mark it as `accepted`, this way you'll gain reputation, and the answerer gains too.

Answer (score 5):

It is a mild joke.  There is an old US military acronym, FUBAR. It is like saying PUT HERE WHAT YOU WILL; It is not localised to Python.

for example:

```
int function1( int value ) { ... }


int function1( string value ) { ... }
```

foo = define the state you need.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 2):

It's an argument. If you define a function as function(), it must be called without arguments. If you define it as function(foo), it must be called with one argument. A copy of this argument is available to the function as a local variable named foo.